# How to delete Nexus user?

Tags: nexus, sonatype

I have inherited administration of a Nexus server and am trying to understand user management.  There are a number of users that are in the default realm and some in the LDAP realm, and I would like to delete users in both realms.

I've been able to disable and remove all roles except for one for users in the default realm (mandatory that it has at least one role associated with it) and all non-LDAP roles for those in the LDAP realm.

What I can't figure out is how to delete users.  Is this even possible?

We are on Nexus 2.11.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be logged in as `admin`, or another user which has the necessary rights and navigate to `Security` / `Users`.

For more details, check the Sonatype book on Nexus [here](http://%20[1]%20https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/confignx-sect-managing-users.html).

Comment: Arrgh!! Now I see the "delete" button in the top header.  I was focused on looking at the selected user profile at the bottome.  :(

Comment: If this solved your issue, perhaps you could upvote and accept the answer...?

Comment: Sorry, thought I had.